# Finding pentagonal numbers and printing them 10 by 10

Tags: java

I have a code to find the [pentagonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number) and print them 10 by 10. However I cannot figure out how to print the pentagonal numbers out other than the final value.

```
public class Lab_6_1{
   public static void main (String[] args){


  System.out.println("Pentagonal Numbers are: ");
  getPentagonalNumber(100);
   }

   public static int getPentagonalNumber(int n){


  int pentNum=((n*(3*n-1))/2);
  final int numPerLine=10;

  for(n=1;n<=100;n++)
  {
  System.out.print(" "+n);
  if (n % 10==0)
  System.out.print("\n");
  }
  System.out.print(pentNum);
  return pentNum;


   }
}
```

I don't want blatant answers. Just advice and/or hints to figure it out.

Comment: Compute pentNum *inside* the loop, not outside.  It has to change on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole logic isn't doing what is supposed to do. I have made following changes and it works as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Pentagonal Numbers are: ");
    getPentagonalNumber(100);
}

public static void getPentagonalNumber(int n) {


    final int numPerLine = 10;
    int pentNum;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        pentNum = ((i * (3 * i - 1)) / 2);
        System.out.print(" " + pentNum);
        if (i % numPerLine == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

As you can see I have made some changes in for loop and calculating the `pentNum` for every time the loop runs and prints it.

Hope this helps

Comment: @DarianLee Glad to help.